Model Derivative API Tutorial Stuck on Step 4 Download OBJ File
I am trying to learn how to use Model Derivative API. Started the tutorial on GitHub, all steps were working fine in Tutorial 1 until Task 4 Download OBJ File, in which i got this error. Any idea how to fix this?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>MissingKey</Code>
    <Message>Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value</Message>
</Error>

enter image description here
I was expecting to send the request, download the translated OBJ File and move on with the next tutorial, am a beginner in Postman and am stuck.

It works for me:

Please double check that all three cookie value pairs have been added correctly. You can convert the request inside the UI e.g. to cURL and compare that to what I'm using:
curl --request GET \
  --url https://cdn.derivative.autodesk.com/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YWRhbV8yMDE5MDMwNzIvMDAtZnVzaW9uLW1vZGVsLWIuaXB0/output/geometry/dee24874-2b6a-3b9a-b091-785f0b005360.obj \
  --header 'Cookie: CloudFront-Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmRlcml2YXRpdmUuYXV0b2Rlc2suY29tL2RYSnVPbUZrYzJzdWIySnFaV04wY3pwdmN5NXZZbXBsWTNRNllXUmhiVjh5TURFNU1ETXdOekl2TURBdFpuVnphVzl1TFcxdlpHVnNMV0l1YVhCMC9vdXRwdXQvZ2VvbWV0cnkvZGVlMjQ4NzQtMmI2YS0zYjlhLWIwOTEtNzg1ZjBiMDA1MzYwLm9iaiIsIkNvbmRpdGlvbiI6eyJEYXRlTGVzc1RoYW4iOnsiQVdTOkVwb2NoVGltZSI6MTcyMTA1NDE4Mn19fV19; Path=/; Domain=cdn.derivative.autodesk.com; HTTPOnly;CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=APKAIJ4JBLIOQMJEURDQ; Path=/; Domain=cdn.derivative.autodesk.com; HTTPOnly;CloudFront-Signature=FWwrOqz9CLHxnFP4l0gE2OzVVcfCiPGCa--8wmYNnMvXBncvWXr6Hu3pxK-vQr-L6NPH8Ft7r8YBFSpjn7nwDOMyZ5s~Xv9UBizx2wo1WPQF6zHRnzJ8QlJGn5R3UxEVaPl9DhygRJfGNeHoEsFF7H51SD7dIbGKi6pfQv2qlz1sOVxpe03v9Jj1VfVxY0xq9e0ORSasRIO~L8nODtalbbyP~WT7FX0VlYkgJwhnDXoYUrY2YpeGJ9Qm3GOBzpJH~vE87SQEM62pnx6QGrdKr1I2CXTa61JOGbXG9RrU4ETUlNIo18LAqJs2TNUKtUuF1qeMeeA3wXkHPTAcyrIC6w__; Path=/; Domain=cdn.derivative.autodesk.com; HTTPOnly'

